# Using update-alternatives just for the current shell

Tags: command-line, compiling, update-alternatives

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10, so the default g++ version is 5.2.1. Since I need to change it to the 4.7 often, I'm using update-alternatives; I've noticed, however, that the default compiler is not restored on closing the terminal; this may be an issue since there is the possibility to mix codes compiled with different compilers. Is there a way to force the shell to restore the default settings on exiting? Thank you in advice.

Edit:
I wish to thank the_Seppi for his precious help

Comment: Don't add "Solved" to the title.

Comment: Sorry, I wished to mark the question solved a la StackExchange way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternatives system only works globally. So you could use something like

```
trap 'sudo update-alternatives ....' EXIT
```

However, this would ask for your password and also would reset it for all other active shells. So I doubt this is what you want.

---

My suggestion: First set the alternative back to the 'default' version of g++. Create something like the following in your `~/.bashrc` file (or whatever your shell uses, when not using bash):

```
function oldg++() {
    alias g++=/path/to/older/g++
}
function newg++() {
    unalias g++
}
```

So now you'll be using the more recent g++ by default, until you run the command `oldg++` This will switch to the older version for the current session or until you execute `newg++`, which deletes the alias and therefore switches back to the default version.